How to connect AKS to Postgres flexible server
I have provisioned an AKS cluster and an Postgres Flexible server. I am able to schedule a deployment from my ACR however I am unable to connect to my DB from my Pod. What am I missing? I am trying to connect via myname.postgres.database.azure.com. I think both AKS and PG are on the same vnet. I am not sure exactly how the privatelink thing is meant to work, this could be the source of my confusion.
│ 2024/06/12 09:28:06 Unable to connect to database: failed to connect to `host=myname-server.postgres.database.azure.com user=user database=database`: hostname resolving error (lookup myname.postgres.database.azure.com on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host)

Core network module
# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "default" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}_rg"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "default" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-vnet"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "default" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "default" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.default.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]

  delegation {
    name = "fs"

    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"

      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "default" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.default.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.default.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "default" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-pdz.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default.name

  depends_on = [azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.default]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "default" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-pdzvnetlink.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.default.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.default.id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "default" {
  name                   = "${var.prefix}-server"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  version                = "13"
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.default.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.default.id
  administrator_login    = "prop"
  administrator_password = var.db_password
  zone                   = "1"
  storage_mb             = 32768
  sku_name               = "GP_Standard_D2s_v3"
  backup_retention_days  = 7

  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.default]
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_database" "default" {
  name      = "${var.prefix}-db"
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.default.id
  collation = "en_US.utf8"
  charset   = "UTF8"
}

AKS Module
# Create cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}_aks"
  dns_prefix          = "${var.prefix}aks"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku_tier            = "Free"

  default_node_pool {
    name                        = "${var.prefix}pool"
    node_count                  = var.node_count
    vm_size                     = var.vm_size
    temporary_name_for_rotation = "${var.prefix}tmp"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin      = "azure"
    network_plugin_mode = "overlay"
    ebpf_data_plane     = "cilium"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}acr"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku                 = "Basic"
  admin_enabled       = true
}

Update
kubectl exec -it busybox -- nslookup myname-server.postgres.database.azure.com                                                                                                           
Server:     10.0.0.10
Address:    10.0.0.10:53

Non-authoritative answer:
myname-server.postgres.database.azure.com   canonical name = e7657xxxxxx.myname-pdz.postgres.database.azure.com

Non-authoritative answer:
myname-server.postgres.database.azure.com   canonical name = e7657xxxxxx.myname-pdz.postgres.database.azure.com

and if I lookup the cname
** server can't find e7657xxxxxx.myname-pdz.postgres.database.azure.com: NXDOMAIN

Somehow the problem is that the AKS DNS has no way to resolve cname here. I have no idea how to resolve this cname from the cluster

Check if these help- https://fusionauth.io/docs/get-started/download-and-install/kubernetes/aks and https://serverfault.com/questions/1089053/how-to-connect-aks-with-postgres-in-private-vnet

Try include "public_network_access_enabled = false" in your resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" configuration  link @Brenwell

Thanks Vinay B. Unfortunately I can't set that. "Can't configure a value for "public_network_access_enabled": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration."

@Arko thanks. However that didn't help. Well at least I couldn't see how it might.

As per the above error, the DNS is not resolving through Azure DNS: 168.63.129.16. If you are using 10.0.0.10 instead of the default, you can create an Azure Private DNS resolver, which will forward the traffic to Azure DNS: 168.63.129.16. Refer to this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns-integration#virtual-network-and-on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder for more details.

@VenkatV You were right. Thanks

If you are able to resolve the issue by creating a Private DNS resolver, I will post the solution with the same points so that it can be useful to the community.

After working through the problem I found a different solution that works better for my specific needs. But my understanding was that your proposal was the missing link, I just didn't implement it. I may still come back to it. If you post your solution I would be happy to mark it as correct. Thanks

│ 2024/06/12 09:28:06 Unable to connect to database: failed to connect to `host=myname-server.postgres.database.azure.com user=user database=database`: hostname resolving error (lookup myname.postgres.database.azure.com on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host)

The error you encountered above is due to DNS not forwarding the traffic to Azure DNS (168.63.129.16) because you are using a custom DNS server (10.0.0.10)
To resolve the issue, you need to configure the Azure DNS resolver to forward the traffic from your custom DNS server to Azure Private DNS (168.63.129.16)
By configuring the DNS resolver, AKS will accept traffic coming from the custom DNS server and resolve the address of your database. Refer to the MS Doc for creating Azure DNS Private Resolver.

Reference: What is Azure DNS Private Resolver?
Azure Private Resolver for virtual network and on-premises workloads
